# Android: OutOfMemoryError while loading xml-layout. What does it mean on how can I avoid it?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, out-of-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: error inflating xml: class unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439207/android-error-inflating-xml-class-unknown)

My app crashes when it's to inflate this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSurvey"
                android:layout_width="80dip"
                android:layout_height="80dip"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/myschedulechanges_icon"
                android:onClick="openSurvey" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnSurvey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                android:text="Mijn\nroosterwijzigingen" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAutomaticCheck"
                android:layout_width="80dip"
                android:layout_height="80dip"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/automaticcheck_icon"
                android:onClick="openAutomaticCheck" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnAutomaticCheck"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                android:text="Automatisch\nchecken" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnManualCheck"
                android:layout_width="80dip"
                android:layout_height="80dip"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/manualcheck_icon"
                android:onClick="openManualCheck" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnManualCheck"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                android:text="Handmatig\nchecken" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

With these error messages:

```
11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.camelotapps.augustinianum/com.camelotapps.augustinianum.ScheduleChangesActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class <unknown>
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class <unknown>
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at com.camelotapps.augustinianum.ScheduleChangesActivity.onCreate(ScheduleChangesActivity.java:18)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  ... 11 more
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  ... 26 more
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2785)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:449)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:104)
    11-18 09:48:15.713: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  ... 29 more
```

Line #46 is the first line of this section:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAutomaticCheck"
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="80dip"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/automaticcheck_icon"
    android:onClick="openAutomaticCheck" />
```

Why am I getting this OutOfMemoryError?
And, even more important, what can I do to avoid it?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the size of automaticcheck_icon ?

Comment: Yes, i think automaticcheck_icon  file is too big. try reducing size by quality control.

Comment: @spanjeta Ok, thank you, I'll try that. Which size would be ok?

Comment: it depend on device you are testing on. You can try small resolution and if that solve the problem, you can later find what image size you device can handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reduced the size of the button's backgound a little bit. And it works fine now!

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the main cause is OutOfMemory When loads a Bitmap, may you loaded too much Bitmaps? if yes you can consider to implement a LRUCache... keep me updated...

Comment: I'm currently trying to make the button's background image a little smaller

Comment: How much kb would you recommend?

Comment: Yeeeeaaaah, I reduced the size just a little bit and it works perfectlly now.

Comment: Ok, well! I don't know how much kb should be a bitmap, but usually a button's background is not so big, so I think it could be under 500kb. Make some check with other VMs (create one with not so much ram), or test it on a low-end device (if you ave one).